# Tableau - IF Statement with aggregation

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I need to do a aggregation under IF statement in a calculated field

1. If a city is the same as selected by the user (parameter `PAR_SELECT_CITY`);
2. In case the condition 1 is true, then `SUM(Number of records) - [PAR_SELECT_QTY]`

   `[PAR_SELECT_QTY]` is a parameter that user choose to deduct from the total quantity
3. In case the condition 1 is false, then `SUM(Number of records)`

   ```
   IF [City] = [PAR_SELECT_CITY] THEN
       SUM([Number of Records])-[PAR_SELECT_QTY]
   ELSE
      SUM([Number of Records])
   END
   ```

However, IF Statament does not accept to mix aggregation and not aggregation

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error suggests, the issue is the mix of aggregate and "row level" data. In Tableau, you ideally want your row level data to be contained within an aggregate function.

i.e. `sum(if true then 1 end)` instead of `if true then sum(1) end`

For your example, you could try

```
SUM([Number of Records])
- 
AVG(IF [City] = [PAR_SELECT_CITY] THEN [PAR_SELECT_QTY] ELSE 0 END)
```

Your `PAR_SELECT_CITY` also needs to return an aggregate number. If `PARA_SELECT_CITY` = 5 (for example) and your dataset contains 100 rows, the AVG(PARA_SELECT_CITY) will also be 5, whereas `SUM(PARA_SELECT_CITY)` would return 500. Therefore the AVG should work as an aggregate function that returns the desired value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I understading now how it works